# cannot SSH beaglebone after changing

Tags: linux, ssh, beagleboard

In order to get internet through USB from my ubuntu host, I changed routing on beaglebone

```
route add default gw 192.168.7.1
```

and change /etc/resolv.conf into

```
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

It gets internet but I cannot ssh beaglebone like before anymore from any host.
Normally I did `ssh root@192.168.7.2`
but it doesn't return any message or prompt to enter password.Just blank waits there.
I there any way to fix it?

Comment: Is your computer you're ssh'ing from on the same IP subnet?

Comment: So I tried a Linux using virtual box on win7 while the beaglebone is connected by a USB. It stopped working. I also tried putty, nothing returned. I'm not sure what you are referring to but beaglebone is connected to a laptop only using a USB while the laptop is connected to WiFi network. I'm using that laptop to ssh beaglebone

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you shouldn't configure `/etc/resolv.conf` with

```
nameserver 192.168.7.1
```

It my happen that the ssh daemon is trying to resolve the reverse of the ip address you're connecting from, and it takes long to timeout, giving you the impression that it does not work.

Comment: oh. That makes sense. But seems the only way to get internet. Is there a way to have both? Or set timeout to 0?

Comment: you have two choices: 1) you get a working reverse with your dns 2) you disbale reverse dns lookups. In this case if you have openssh just follow this http://www.yaleman.org/2007/12/09/ssh-reverse-dns-lookup-disable/ , but I cannot understand it from what you say if you're using it or if if you're using something else like dropbear . To make sure: having a working DNS is the ciorrect solution, option number 2 is a hack.

Comment: Every I restart the beaglebone, it will restore /etc/resolv.conf automatically. And the default is `nameserver 127.0.0.1`    Also, command route returns `Destination 192.168.7.0  Gateway 0.0.0.0  mask 255.255.255.252  Flags U Ref 0  Use 0 Iface usb0`. ifconfig returns `usb0 net addr:192.168.7.2 Bcast:192.168.7.3` On the host: `ipv4 addr: 192.168.0.110, default gw 192.168.0.1` Would it because I disabled gnome from start up so it shuts down some default configuration?

Comment: dude, your network configuration is a mess. If on usb0 you have address 192.168.7.2 netmask 255.255.255.0 then broadcast has to be 192.168.7.255. Your pc has to be configured with ip address 192.168.7.1, which has to be set as default gateway on the beaglebone. Then DNS has to be configured accordingly to your network configuration. But all these problems are not in topic with programming, but with basic linux usage, thus if you need more information, you'd better ask on superuser.